# Angular 8: why does value load to alert only after 2 clicks

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I give the user a list of company id's to choose from, and according to the one he choose I want the company password to display in an alert button (later to show in a table).
The first click brings the correct values through the network (i see it in the request and response details), but the alert displays the correct password only after 2 clicks.
the list of available companies comes from a service called `companyService`.

I'm using Angular version 8.  I tried debugging through the browser to see what the `httpRequest` returns but it is okay on the first click.  the `companyId` is also initialized well after the first click.

Html code:

```html
<h1>Select the company you wish to update:</h1>
<select [(ngModel)]="companyId">
    <option *ngFor="let c of companyService.allCompanies">{{c.id}}</option>
</select>
<br>
<button (click)="fillCompanyDetails()">Find this company</button>
```

TS code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CompanyService } from 'src/app/shared/services/company.service';
import { Company } from 'src/app/shared/models/company';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-company',
  templateUrl: './update-company.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-company.component.css']
})
export class UpdateCompanyComponent implements OnInit {

companyId:number;
originalCompany:Company;

  constructor(public companyService:CompanyService, public httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  fillCompanyDetails(){
    this.httpClient.get<Company>(`${this.companyService.baseUrl}admin/company/${this.companyId}`)
    .subscribe(res => this.originalCompany = res, err => alert(err));
    alert(this.originalCompany.password);
  }

}
```

This is the companyService which contains the baseUrl and allCompanies:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Company } from '../models/company';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CompanyService {

    baseUrl: string = "http://localhost:8080/CouponSystem/sec/";

    public allCompanies: Company[];
    public companyToUpdate:Company;

    public constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
        //adding this into constructor since this data is frequently needed.
        this.httpClient.get<Company[]>(`${this.baseUrl}admin/companies`)
            .subscribe(res => this.allCompanies = res, err => this.errorString = err);
    }
```

This is the Company model:

```js
export class Company{

public constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public name?: string,
    public password?: string,
    public email?: string
){}

}
```

When clicked the first time, the button shows what companyId held previously (if it's the first time I get an error of 'undefined'.  The second time shows correctly.
I expect the companyId chosen to be already in the variable upon the first click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observables are async meaning you don't get the response immediately but once they are resolved.

So if you want to use the latest data emitted from your observable put your logic inside subscribe.

```
fillCompanyDetails(){
    this.httpClient.get<Company>(`${this.companyService.baseUrl}admin/company/${this.companyId}`)
      .subscribe((res) => {
          this.originalCompany = res;
          alert(this.originalCompany.password);
       },
          err => alert(err)
       );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it like this

```js
  fillCompanyDetails(){
    this.httpClient.get<Company>(`${this.companyService.baseUrl}admin/company/${this.companyId}`)
    .subscribe(res => {
    this.originalCompany = res;
    alert(this.originalCompany.password);
    }, err => alert(err));
  }
```

The alert is being called before the originalCompany is set. Because its async it would make sense that the value isnt set until the second time.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fillCompanyDetails` function should look like this

```
fillCompanyDetails(){
    this.httpClient.get<Company>(`${this.companyService.baseUrl}admin/company/${this.companyId}`)
.subscribe(res => { 
     this.originalCompany = res;
     alert(this.originalCompany.password);
 }, err => {alert(err)}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use, subscribe, you are telling the program, hey HttpClient i'm sending a request to get companies, let me know when you have got back the response  i need (subscribe to the response). I'll do other things in the mean time (the other thing being the alert it calls it right away, hence you get nothing). The next time you click it, the request is already processed so you get the right value. Moving the alert inside your subscribe part should do the trick, as it will only alert once there is a response.

```
fillCompanyDetails(){
    this.httpClient.get<Company> 
    (`${this.companyService.baseUrl}admin/company/${this.companyId}`)
    .subscribe((res:company) =>{
                this.originalCompany = res;  
                alert(this.originalCompany.password);
              },         
              err => alert(err));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - now I understand the 'behind the scenes' better.

Comment: Glad to help :)